# Calling custom hook in event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook named `useFetchMyApi` wrapping a fetch call to API endpoint. The function hook accepts a parameter and it is included in the post body. The data array output is dependent on the hook parameter.

On the UI, the App component calls `useFetchMyApi` once. A button click handler will call subsequent `useFetchMyApi` to update a list on the UI.

My issues:

1. I can't call `useFetchMyApi` in the event handler because it violates the rules of hook.
2. How do I refresh the list of items dependent on the response of `useFetchMyApi`?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const useFetchMyApi = (location = "") => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // let's stimulate the API call with a 2 seconds response time
    setTimeout(() => setItems([location, Math.random()]), 5000);
  }, [location]);
  return { items };
};

export default function App() {
  const locationSelect = useRef(null);
  const { items } = useFetchMyApi("mylocation1");
  const onButtonClicked = (event) => {
    const selectedLocation = locationSelect.current.value;
    // Call api and refresh items by location
    // Fix here??
    //useFetchMyApi(selectedLocation);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select ref={locationSelect}>
        <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={onButtonClicked}>Refresh</button>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-water-1o6mz?file=/src/App.js:0-1055

Comment: Why you do not declare the items as App` state ?

Comment: @thelonglqd the items list is to be managed by the custom hook, no?

Comment: you can't, you will need to modify the hook to return a function that performs the fetch, right now your hook depends on the location argument, not by an onClick event.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Issues

> 1. I can't call `useFetchMyApi` in the event handler because it violates the rules of hooks.

Correct, react hooks can only be called from the body of functional components and other react hooks. They can not be conditionally invoked, such as in an asynchronous callback, or in loops.

> 2. How do I refresh the list of items dependent on the response of `useFetchMyApi`?

You've nothing in `App` to trigger a rerender to trigger the effect in order to trigger the effect's callback.

## Solution

You should leverage the `useEffect` hook's dependency in your custom `useFetchMyApi` hook to refresh the list of items. Add some local component state to represent the "currently" selected location. Use your button's `onClick` callback to update the state and trigger a rerender which then will rerun your custom hook.

```
const useFetchMyApi = (location = "") => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // let's stimulate the API call with a 2 seconds response time
    setTimeout(() => setItems([location, Math.random()]), 2000);
  }, [location]); // <-- effect callback triggers when location updates
  return { items };
};

function App() {
  const locationSelect = useRef(null);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("mylocation1"); // <-- add state
  const { items } = useFetchMyApi(location); // <-- pass location value to hook

  const onButtonClicked = () => {
    const selectedLocation = locationSelect.current.value;
    setLocation(selectedLocation); // <-- update state, trigger rerender
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select ref={locationSelect}>
        <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={onButtonClicked}>Refresh</button>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit calling-custom-hook-in-event-handler]

## Alternative Solution

An alternative solution would be to rewrite your custom `useFetchMyApi` hook to also return a callback to be invoked on-demand in a click handler to do the fetch and update the list. Here is a simple conversion. *Notice now the returned fetch function consumes the location, not the hook call.*

```
const useFetchMyApi = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  // custom fetch function consumes location
  const locationFetch = (location = "") => {
    // let's stimulate the API call with a 2 seconds response time
    setTimeout(() => setItems([location, Math.random()]), 2000);
  };
  
  return [items, locationFetch]; // <-- return state and fetch function
};

export default function App() {
  const locationSelect = useRef(null);
  const [items, locationFetch] = useFetchMyApi(); // <-- destructure state and fetch function

  useEffect(() => {
    locationFetch("mylocation1");
  }, []); // <-- initial mounting fetch call

  const onButtonClicked = () => {
    const selectedLocation = locationSelect.current.value;
    locationFetch(selectedLocation); // <-- invoke fetch function
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select ref={locationSelect}>
        <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={onButtonClicked}>Refresh</button>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit calling-custom-hook-in-event-handler (forked)]

Comment: thank you for the very helpful and detailed explanation. State drives the UI and not components / hooks. My mistake was thinking that hooks can directly influence other components / hooks.