# Proper way to call a hook from an event handler

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm working on an app for my volunteer org and running into what I am sure are rookie errors on trying to power into app dev w/o considering proper development methods/architecture in React v18.2 and Next v13.4.7.

With that said, I'm trying to call an API after an `onChange` handler from a select field so I can populate a second select field with updated **Districts**, based on the chosen **Province**
[image]

I'm using a useEffect to call my handleDistricts function *(which has a Component inside it)*, but getting errors in the API service it calls and not sure where I need to fix the code so I can have proper architecture for my Components and able to call the APIs to load data.

Here's my code for [DisplayDistricts](https://github.com/TimLavelle/cv-patient-platform/blob/feature/registration/app/_utils/displayDistricts.js) component holding the function and useEffect call:

```js
'use client'

import { Field, useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import GetDistrictsAPI from '@/_utils/services/GetDistrictsAPI';
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function DisplayDistricts(props) {

  const { setFieldValue, values } = useFormikContext();
  let passedProvID = props.idProvince;

  let [selectedDistricts, setSelectedDistricts] = useState({
    data: [{ dist_id: '0', name: 'Select a Province first' }]
  });

  // This is the area where I'm calling the GetDistrictsAPI Component and likely where my error is
  const handleDistricts = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('Province passed = ' + passedProvID)

    GetDistrictsAPI(passedProvID).then(data => {
      console.log('Province District Data is ', data)
      setSelectedDistricts(data);
    });

  }, [passedProvID]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDistricts();
  }, [passedProvID, handleDistricts]);

  return (
    <Field
      as="select"
      id="pxDistrict"
      name="pxDistrict"
      disabled={!values.pxProvince}
      onChange={(e) => {
        handleDistricts()
        setFieldValue('pxDistrict', e.target.value)
      }}
      className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
    >
      {selectedDistricts.data.map((p, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={p.dist_id}>{p.name}</option>
      ))}
    </Field>
  )
}
```

And the [GetDistrctsAPI](https://github.com/TimLavelle/cv-patient-platform/blob/feature/registration/app/_utils/services/GetDistrictsAPI.js) component is where I am getting the Hook error:

```js
import useSWR from "swr";
import axios from "axios";

export default function GetDistrictsAPI(provID) {

  let query;
  provID ? query = `?province_id=${provID}` : query = ''

  const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);

  // The error is happening here, after the useSWR
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/districts${query}`, fetcher);

  console.log('Get Districts called', data)

  return data
}
```

[image]

And here's my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "patient-platform",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@docsearch/react": "^3.5.1",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@markdoc/next.js": "^0.2.2",
    "@sindresorhus/slugify": "^2.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "focus-visible": "^5.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "i18next": "^23.2.6",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.2",
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "next-i18next": "^14.0.0",
    "postcss-focus-visible": "^8.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^2.0.6",
    "query-to-mongo": "^0.10.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.1",
    "server-only": "^0.0.1",
    "swr": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but still trying to wrap my head around proper use of hooks.

Any ideas/thoughts are appreciated!

Cheers
Tim

Comment: look like the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632532/how-to-initialize-a-redux-store-value-from-another-value-in-the-same-store-react/76632671

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at it and tried a few things, but still getting the same error.

Comment: rename `GetDistrictsAPI` to `useGetDistrictsAPI`

Comment: Thanks mate - I did try that, but then I was getting additional errors saying I couldn't use a hook in a callback function. I'm going to spend some time reading through the link in the post you referenced.

Comment: Can you edit your question to share your package.json as well?

Comment: No worries mate, I've got it at on GH here: https://github.com/TimLavelle/cv-patient-platform/blob/feature/registration/package.json

Comment: I've now also added it in @SuryasishPaul

Comment: As it appears, there are two problems here: first you'll have to change the name of your hook to useGetDistrictsApi(), which is the simple part. Next you gotta call your custom hook outside the event handler. Solving these two issues should get your code working. You can take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65473077/19119712  Code that solves your problem might look somewhat similar to the one in the link. Trying to think of something in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

hooks can only be used in top level of component

rename the function to useGetDistrictsAPI

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import axios from "axios";

//this will make the function act as a custom hook
export default function useGetDistrictsAPI(provID) {

  let query;
  provID ? query = `?province_id=${provID}` : query = ''

  const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);

  // The error is happening here, after the useSWR
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/districts${query}`, fetcher);
    
  return {data}
}
```

then in your component at top level you have to use it like this and access the data

```
const {data} = useGetDistrictsAPI(provID)
```

the error you encountered was because you are calling GetDistrictsAPI  inside handleDistricts useCallBack and this function has useSwr hook. as hooks can only be used at top level. it is throwing this error

for your specific use case wrap the fetch code inside another function in useGetDistrictsAPI and return that function  from useGetDistrictsAPI instead of returning data and then call that function inside your handler

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what @surayishpaul was talking about as well and I will look into it. It's been a busy few days but can hopefully take a look at it this afternoon.